# Setting the URI of a React Native Image Component to an Object Key

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I'm trying to have a simple app that displays an array of film objects (with keys such as 'title','year', and 'poster' as a ScrollView where each film is displayed with its name, year and poster. However when I try to pass the poster key through the Image component nothing happens. my poster key is a string url from the omdbapi. How do I fix this?

Here's my code

```
    const ToFilm = movies => {
  return(
    <View style = {styles.filmContainer}>
      <Image source = {{uri: movies.poster}}/>
      <Text>{movies.title}</Text>
      <Text>{movies.year}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? what is your error? That looks like valid, can you show the value of movies? Based on your naming it seems like it would be an array

Comment: Sorry thats poor naming, movies is a single film object with a title, year and poster. At first it was throwing me a syntax errror but I checked again and now the image is simply not displaying.

Comment: `Image` requires a `height` and `width` style, try adding that and seeing if it's visible  - `<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri: movies.poster}}/>` change values accordingly.

Comment: That fixed it @Dan thanks